# Uploading different source files to different subdomains

Tags: language-agnostic

So I have multiple subdomains on my site.  One of them, the blog subdomain, has a WordPress blog.  I've uploaded the `index.htm` file to the server, but now that one index file is visible for all my subdomains.  How would I change this so that different subdomains can have different `index.html` files?

Comment: How is your server setup to point the subdomains to proper code?  It sounds like your subdomains all hit the same code.  You need to separate them so they each have their own folder structure.

Comment: I know that.  What I'm asking is how

Comment: where is your site hosted?  They should have a way to setup subdomains and point them to specific a code base.

Comment: Fatcow.  I may or may not be missing anything, I'm kind of new to web development

Answer (score 0):

Here's a knowledge base article to setup a subdomain on fatcow.  I don't have my login information for my fatcow account here but if this doesn't help I can do some more looking tonight and help you out more.

http://www.fatcow.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=2939

Here's a good video on how to use their Domain pointing Manager

http://www.fatcow.com/support/tutorials/DomainPointingManager.html